# Synchronize local database with Google ads

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-ads-api

I am trying to update the local database with the updated data of the Google ads accounts (information, budget and expenses of the account).  I am currently performing this task every 8 hours but the way to do it is not optimal since it makes the requests for each account, that is, when updating it obtains the list of accounts and then one by one it obtains the budget and expense data in separate functions.  What I need is if you can help me with an efficient way to do this task and if it can be done using batch jobs, please guide me since I haven't found much related to the subject and the examples I've seen with batch jobs are for modify or create resources, nunk to get information.  Sorry if I didn't know how to express myself very well in the question but I would really appreciate your collaboration.

An example of my function

````
    def listGoogleAccounts(id: str): 

         try: 

             googleads_client = GoogleAdsClient.load_from_storage('./google-ads.yaml') 

             googleads_service = googleads_client.get_service("GoogleAdsService") 

             status_list = ["UNSPECIFIED", "UNKNOWN", "ENABLED", "CANCELED", "SUSPENDED", "CLOSED"] 

             query = """ 

                 SELECT 

                     customer_client.descriptive_name, 

                     customer_client.id, 

                     customer_client.status 

                 FROM customer_client 

                 WHERE customer_client.manager = false AND customer_client.level >= 1""" 

  

             account = accounts.find_one({'_id': ObjectId(id)}) 

             assigned_mcc = account['mcc'] 

             client_currency = account['currency'] 

             google_accounts_list = [] 

             if(assigned_mcc == []): 

                 accounts.find_one_and_update({'_id': ObjectId(id)}, {'$set': {'accounts_list': []}}) 

             if(assigned_mcc != False): 

                 for mcc in assigned_mcc: 

                     # Get all accounts from the customer_client 

                     stream = googleads_service.search_stream( 

                         customer_id=str(mcc['id']), query=query 

                     ) 

                     # Iterate the response 

                     for batch in stream: 

                         for googleads_row in batch.results: 

                             # Get a customer_client from the customer_clients list 

                             customer_client = googleads_row.customer_client 

                             is_canceled = canceled.find_one({'customer_id': str(customer_client.id)}) 

                             buyer = buyers.find_one({'account': str(customer_client.id)}) 

                             invitations = [] 

                             for customer in account['accounts_list']: 

                                 if customer['id'] == customer_client.id: 

                                     if 'invitations' in customer: 

                                         invitations = customer['invitations'] 

                             google_accounts_list.append({ 

                                 "id": customer_client.id, 

                                 "descriptive_name": customer_client.descriptive_name, 

                                 "allocated": is_canceled['allocated'] if is_canceled != None else 0, 

                                 "spent": is_canceled['spent'] if is_canceled != None else 0, 

                                 "manager": mcc['descriptive_name'], 

                                 "buyer": buyer['buyer'] if buyer != None else '-', 

                                 "currency": client_currency, 

                                 "status": status_list[customer_client.status] if is_canceled == None else 'CANCELED', 

                                 "invitations": invitations 

                             }) 

             UserController.checkForLinkedAccounts(id, google_accounts_list) 

             UserController.getAccountBudgetFromClientList(googleads_client, google_accounts_list)```

Synchronize local bd data with Google ads updated data
````